# Не скрывается элемент при использование jquery 3.3.1

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет! У меня возник глупый вопрос, а именно, почему при заданной высоте не скрывается элемент?

```js
< script >
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // если пользователь прокрутил страницу более чем на 850px
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
      // то сделать кнопку scrollup видимой
      $('.down').fadeIn();
    }
    // иначе скрыть кнопку scrollup
    else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 850) {
      $('.down').fadeOut();
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $('.down').fadeOut();
    }
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
.down {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: .3;
    animation: sizeDown 2s infinite alternate; /*  анимация повторения*/
}

@keyframes sizeDown {    /* Название анимации, которое идет после в animation */
    from {               /* От */
      width: 60px;
      height: 100px;              
    }
    to {                /* До */
      width: 80px;
      height: 120px;      
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="down">
        <img src="lookDown.png" width="80px" height="100px">
    </div>
```

Ошибку не вижу, скорее всего именно jquery. Версия 3.3.1. Все что связанно с  элементом прикрепил.

2 if  нужен для скрытия элемента если выше заданной высоты. 
Но вот 3 не работает, он не скрывается..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Третье условие не работает потому что всегда выполняется первое условие. 
Попробуйте вот так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
// если пользователь прокрутил страницу более чем на 850px и меньше чем 1000
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 1000) {
  // то сделать кнопку scrollup видимой
  $('.down').fadeIn();
}
// иначе скрыть кнопку scrollup
else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 850) {
  $('.down').fadeOut();
} else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
  $('.down').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Comment: Окей, я закрыл первый скрип и отделил их. 

Но теперь при дохождении 1100 она начинает мигать ..

Comment: Вау. Теперь работает. Совсем не знаком с Jq, в шоке, огромное спасибо!